# Simple tuple operation

Tags: c-preprocessor

Say I have a tuple:

```
#define T (a, b)
```

How can I extract first and second element of the tuple in gcc, without use of any external libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one way of doing this. I'm not sure if this would work in anything else than gcc.

```
#define first_(x, y) x
#define first(t) first_ t

#define second_(x, y) y
#define second(t) second_ t

#define T (a, b)

first(T) // expands to a
second(T) // expands to b
```